# modifying URL - whitelabeling/VHosts

Tags: apache, xampp, vhosts, white-labelling

I have recently implemented white labeling, and after changing my VHOSTS setting I have found that some of the URL is stripped, for example:

```
<VirtualHost *:8166>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   DocumentRoot C:\xampp5.2test\htdocs\portal
   ServerName xampp

   <Directory "C:\xampp5.2test\htdocs\portal">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

is configured like this within apache vhosts. However when one writes localhost:8166 in address bar example:

http://localhost:8166/ url is like this and not

http://localhost:8166/portal

Like above, how can I get it to append the full path to the url

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation just changing the document root should make it:

```
<VirtualHost *:8166>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   DocumentRoot C:\xampp5.2test\htdocs
   ServerName xampp
   RewriteEngine On


   RewriteRule ^/*$ /portal

   <Directory "C:\xampp5.2test\htdocs\portal">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hi tried that, however when I type in "localhost:8166", it doesn't append portal:

http://localhost:8166/portal/ to the end of it. Rather in the address bar it will be like this:

http://localhost:8166/

Thanks.

Comment: if you want the / page to redirect you have to specify it, see my edit

Comment: When I do that, it creates a neverending loop. /portalportalportalportal, anyway i can append it only once?

Comment: Seems like Vhosts didn't like that, it is not allowing me to restart apache.

Comment: does your server have mod-rewrite, it needs to be present.

Comment: Cheers. It was disabled, enabled it. Still not having any luck with the above code.

Comment: yep, when I added:  RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^/$ /portal , no luck